# Como desabilitar e habilitar a função .Click() de um span quando eu clicar em outro span usando on() off()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho dois spans que funcionam como botões, ao clicar neles aparece um input para colocar um e-mail e se clicar de novo esconde esses inputs.

Eu consegui fazer o seguinte:

Clico no span1 -> Aparece o input1 e desabilita o span2, e se clicar de novo nele esconde o input1 ***porem não habilita o span2***

E eu gostaria que ao clicar de novo nele alem de esconder o input1 ele habilita-se o span2, uma espécie de `toggle()` no `off();`

Segue o JS:

```js
$('.new-step-email-aluno').hide();
  $('#btn-aluno').on('click', function() {
   $('.new-step-email-aluno').toggle();
   $('#btn-familiar').off();
  });

  $('.new-step-email-familiar').hide();
  $('#btn-familiar').on('click', function() {
   $('.new-step-email-familiar').toggle();
   $('#btn-aluno').off();
  });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se ficou claro, qualquer coisa eu arrumo. vlw

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma solução

```js
$(function() {

  var $buttons = $('#btn-aluno,#btn-familiar');
  var $input = $('.new-step-email-aluno, .new-step-email-familiar');

  $buttons.on('click', function(e) {

    var $self = $(this);
    var active = $self.is('.active');
    var aluno = $self.is('#btn-aluno');
    var already = $('#btn-aluno.active , #btn-familiar.active').size() > 0;
    //Desabilita o click se houver um ativo.
    if (!active && already)
      return;

    if (!active) {

      if (aluno) {
        $('.new-step-email-aluno').show();
        $('.new-step-email-familiar').hide();
      } else {
        $('.new-step-email-aluno').hide();
        $('.new-step-email-familiar').show();

      }
    } else
      $input.hide();

    $buttons.removeClass('active');

    if (!active)
      $self.addClass('active');

  });

});
```

```css
form { text-align:center;}
#btn-aluno , #btn-familiar { cursor: pointer; }
.new-step-email-familiar , .new-step-email-aluno { display:none;}
.active { border: 2px solid #333 !important; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flat-ui/2.2.2/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="btn-aluno" class="btn btn-primary">Sou aluno</span><br> <input type="text" name="fname" class="new-step-email-aluno"><br>
<span id="btn-familiar" class="btn btn-primary">Sou familiar</span><br>
<input type="text" name="fname" class="new-step-email-familiar" ><br>
```

Comment: Tentei adaptar ao meu código e não deu certo, lembrando que uso spans e não buttons pq tenho mais button na mesma pagina e tenho mais inputs tambem.  Eu tentei usar um if para ver se o input esta com display none caso não estiver ele desabilita e caso tiver ele habilita, mas não deu certo tb.

Comment: basta substituir os trechos  `var $buttons = $('button');` por `var $buttons = $('#btn-aluno,#btn-familiar');` e `var $input = $('input');` por `var $input = $('.new-step-email-familiar');` além de `var aluno = $self.is('#aluno');` por `var aluno = $self.is('#btn-aluno');` e `var already = $('button.active').size() > 0;` por `var already = $('#btn-aluno.active,#btn-familiar.active').size() > 0;`

Comment: Fazendo estes replaces meu código vai funcionar no seu html.

Comment: Cara eu consegui resolver, era simples, nao sei se posso editar meu post com o link da ajuda q resolver o problema.

Comment: atualizei o código pra você com a solução já que voce estava tendo dificuldade em colocar em seu html